# Problem of interpretation/application of the Cauchy boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was looking for the analytical solution of the 2D advection-diffusion equation on a rectangular domain $\Omega= (0, a)\times(0, b)$ considering:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& C_t +\lambda C + \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}C  - \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{D} \nabla C) = 0, \text{ for } (x, y, t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R^*_+} , \\
& C(x,y,t=0) = \rho(x,y) = f(x)g(y), \text{ for } (x,y) \in \Omega,\\
& f(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1, &x \in [x_0,x_1]\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{array} \right.
g(y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1, &y \in [y_0,y_1]\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{array} \right. \\
& C(x=0,y,t) = C(x=a,y,t) =  0, t \in \mathbb{R^*_+},\\
& \partial_y C(x,y=0,t) = \partial_y C(x,y=b,t) =  0, t \in \mathbb{R^*_+},\\
& \mathbf{u}=(u_x=0,u_y=cst>0)
\label{problem}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I achieved this by using the method of separation of variables (and Fourier) $C(x,y,t)=X(x)Y(y)T(t)$.

However, I wonder whether the application of a Cauchy Boundary Condition (BC) (which imposes both the value of the function and its normal derivative) for the parts of the domain boundary where $y=0$ and $y=b$, makes sense?

Indeed, by applying the method of separation of variables, I must consider for $Y(y)$, the following solution:
\begin{equation}
Y(y)=\exp{(\gamma y)}\big(A\cos{(\eta y)}+B\sin{(\eta y)}\big).
\end{equation}
where $\gamma\pm i\eta$ are the complex solutions of the characteristic polynomial:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\gamma\pm i\eta     & =\frac{-u_x}{-2D_x}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{-2D_x}, \\
                    & =\frac{u_x}{2D_x}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{2D_x}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I notice that the problem is overdetermined with Cauchy BC for example:  $\partial_y C(x,y=0,t)=\partial_y C(x,y=b,t)=0$ et $C(x,y=0,t)=C(x,y=b,t)=0$. Does it mean that the Cauchy BC leads to a ill-posed problem?

If it is possible to "force" this Cauchy BC when solving numerically with a code, can we conclude that the result given by the code is meaningless?

Thank you